# Javascript accessing nested elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, multi-level

I have an array that kind of looks like this:

```
result = {
   akch_generation: 11841,
   akch_chassis: [{
    akch_sp: [{
        akch_faulted: false,
        akch_present: true,
        akch_fru: 'hc:///chassis=0/sp=0'
    }],
    akch_fan: [{
   ....
 }
```

And I want to get to the value of **akch_faulted**, but I can't figure out how.

I tried:

```
hardware.config().akch_chassis.akch_sp => result = undefined

hardware.config().akch_chassis.akch_sp.akch_faulted =>
error: illegal argument expression: "hardware.config().akch_chassis.akch_sp has
   no properties"
```

where hardware.config() is the command I run to get the result array.

I can only get as deep as akch_chassis...

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `result.akch_chassis[0].akch_sp[0].akch_faulted`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! It's a pitty you didn't reply where the answer section is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `result` is not an array, is an object.

The problem is that yours nested objects are inside arrays so to access the property **akch_faulted** you need to write this:

```
result.akch_chassis[0].akch_sp[0].akch_faulted
```

Comment: already tried both of them, but it's not working:
hardware.config().akch_chassis.akch_sp.akch_faulted
error: illegal argument expression: "hardware.config().akch_chassis.akch_sp has
       no properties"

hardware.config() gives me that object.

Comment: @Cristina could you post your whole code in a fiddle?

Comment: I'¡m afarid I can't. I run this command hardware.config() on a machine, and it displays this object (which is quite large).

Comment: I don't think that your comments are very useful ? By definition an array is an object, so there is not really "array notation" ? Did i said a mistake ?

Comment: @Superdrac the comment is for identify the 2 different ways you can use to access the properties. "Array notation" is a way to call it, I also can say 'key notation' vs 'dot notation' but I think is not relevant is just for distinguish both.

Comment: I don't know if it was Saajan or you who answered first, but I'll give you the answer because you justified it well. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to get the value in javascript .

var myvalue = result.akch_chassis[0].akch_sp[0].akch_faulted

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="my.json"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var myvalue = result.akch_chassis[0].akch_sp[0].akch_faulted;
console.log(myvalue);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works! Thank you so much! Now I see the logics behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpfull,

```
  for(var i=0;i<=result.akch_chassis.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<=result.akch_chassis[i].akch_sp.length;j++){
       var value=result.akch_chassis[i].akch_sp[j].akch_faulted;
     }
    }
```